# Laravel Eloquent: Get current id from inner function

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I know, we can do this in the controller:

```
User::with('post')->get();
```

It will get every user's post from the database, based on `users.id`.
But the problem is, I want to do this:

```
User::with(['post' => function($query) {
    # Throw users.id here...
}])->get();
```

How to do that?

Comment: You cannot get the value of user's ID there. That's because you haven't executed your query, thus PHP hasn't received the data yet.

Comment: @Hkan what alternative I can use? Can I put the function inside get()?

Comment: Why do you need the ID in that function?

Comment: I want to call multiple mysql function like MAX(), MIN(), COUNT() inside `select()` using `DB::raw()`. Since eloquent always returning null using `DB::raw()`, I want to run a basic query builder in that function instead.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it through Eloquent queries. You probably need to query those MAXes and MINs separately and inject the results into User models with a loop.

Comment: @Hkan it could be used as an alternative. But, is there a way to merge the post results so the post belongs to the user?

Comment: Yeah, it will be merged. The said loop should be like this: `$users->each(function ($user) use ($foundPosts) { $user->setRelation('post', {find this user's posts from $foundPosts array here}); });`

Comment: Thanks @Hkan. Had been wasting three days to solve this problem. At least I understand now, eloquent only work for basic get. This should be posted as an alternative answer, who knows you would help any new laravel user to not get lost and also can help me to gain new privileg :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the users first, and then load related posts with a separate query and merge them manually.

```
$users = User::get();

$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users->pluck('id'))->get(); // Get your additional data in this query

$users->each(function ($user) use ($posts)
{
    $user->posts = $posts->where('user_id', $user->id);
});
```

**Note:** I did not test the code above. It's just an example to show you how to accomplish what you are trying to do.